# Difference between "numbers analysis" and "number analysis"

Tags: grammatical-number

The company I work for offers an analysis of a business’s financials.

We'd love to call it either of “numbers analysis” or “number analysis”, whichever is grammatically correct!

Comment: Note that this is really driving me nuts. I have a personal preference but can't find any other words like this one, in the same circumstances, with the same rules applying to it.

Comment: What about "Numerical Analysis"?

Comment: Well, that's not what I was asking for! I'm looking for an answer to the question, not an alternative solution. Thanks for trying though :)

Comment: They both sound strange. I'd avoid both unless I was familiar with other similar use in the field. As to the grammaticality, they're equally correct, but not semantically identical.

Comment: Then let me rephrase the question to ask for the difference.

Comment: THe choice between singular and plural attributive nouns is usually resolved by choosing the singular alternative (girl power, dog biscuit/s, cat flap/s, duck soup, car park/s, germ warfare, service station/s ... BUT sports centre/s, ideas man/men ...). But it remains a choice where an accepted form has not yet been established. It can't be called 'ungrammatical' if you choose to use a form other than an accepted one. But it _can_ be called quirky (or worse)....

Comment: [These Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=number+analysis%2Cnumbers+analysis%2Cnumerical+analysis&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnumber%20analysis%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnumbers%20analysis%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnumerical%20analysis%3B%2Cc0) could be used by those wishing to avoid 'quirky'. Or those not wishing to.

Comment: @medica A man was going to give three gifts to people he met that day: $1 000 000, $300 and $250. Would you prefer the $300 or the $250?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth what does that have to do with the question?

Comment: @posdef The Help Center gives the regulation 'Your questions should be reasonably scoped'. I'm using a metaphor to make the point that 'Of the two alternatives B and C, which is grammatically correct? ... We'd love to use the correct one', when both are not ungrammatical but A would be most people's choice, **isn't** reasonably scoped. I was also addressing medica, whose answer seemed inadequate to OP for some reason.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I see... I just thought that your comment was addressed towards medica, which didnt make sense to me. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I would say that "financial analysis" is the correct term.  ["Numerical analysis"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_analysis) is an entirely different field, and "number/numbers analysis" sounds more like a bookie business.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - I see what you did there. Very interesting..

Answer (score -1):

I would rather call it Financial Analysis. But since you want me to pick one of the two you mentioned, I would have go with Numbers Analysis, simply because one number really doesn't require significant analysis.

"How are we doing financially?  Let's analyze the number!"

Comment: So you always use cars parks?

Comment: No, I park on the street, in a garage, or in a parking lot.